# Getting historic Sentinel-5P air quality data for Saudi Arabia

Tags: air-quality

Is there a way to provide  data from Sentinel-5P for the air quality of Saudi Arabia for years 2018 and 2019 in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you check the [Copernicus website](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-5p/data-products)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you describe in more details what data would you like to have in your spreadsheet? Are you looking for the subset of S5P data clipped by the boundaries of Saudi Arabia, or for some aggregation? Are you looking for daily data or for annual or monthly averages? Are you looking for total column or for ground level data? Also what parameters are you interested in?